# Model the probability distribution of the nth term given a set of sequence?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-walk, trees

**Given Data:** X Sequences each of n terms. n is small number around 20, While X is greater than 1000.

- Z1 = A11, A12, A13, A14, A15, .. A1n
- Z2 = A21, A22, A23, A24, A25, .. A2n
- .
- .
- ZX = Ax1, Ax2, Ax3, Ax4, Ax5, .. Axn

First term of all X Sequences are 1. A11 = A21 = A31 = .. An1 = 1 You can get the next term in a sequence by adding/subtracting a small amount, definitely less than 0.1, usually even smaller. It is very similar to a random walk starting from 1 each time increasing/decreasing the value by a small percentage of the past value.

From only the data calculate the probability distribution of A(n) given A(1), This is the density plot of (A1n, A2n, ... Axn). In a random walk this would a bell curve with mean at 1.

The data isn't random, there are patterns, the density plot of (A1n, A2n, ... Axn) shows A(n) is more likely to be less than 1, usually by a small amount.

**Question:**

1. Given A(1) and A(2) calculate the probability distribution of A(n) ?
2. Given A(1), A(2), .. A(x) calculate the probability distribution of
       A(n) ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use MathJax (for more details see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Just asking homework questions in this forum without saying anything about what you've tried and where you are stuck will get your question downvoted and usually closed (I'm surprised you've gone so without any such votes already.) Please edit your question (edit link is on the left opposite your name) to add details. We are interested in helping people learn mathematics themselves here, not in doing their homework for them.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair This isnt a home work question, something I am interested in solving because I find it interesting. I have no idea where to begin. The only solution I could think of is check if A(2) > A(1) If so Scale Everything Linearly such that A(1) is 1 and A(2) is 1.1 and figure out the density curve of A(n) and then scale A(n) down again. If A(1) > A(2), Scale so that A(2) is 0.9, The first question that comes to mind is what sort of scale is useful in such situations. Is this a sub-field in mathematics, can I read about it somewhere ?